# Kubernetes in RasPi 4B does not detect RAM

Tags: kubernetes, raspbian, kubeadm

I'm trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster on a bunch of Raspberry Pi 4B nodes. I adopted the setup I use for my v-kube-cluster (Kubernetes in virtual boxed using vagrant). See https://github.com/sebastian9486/v-kube-cluster (but not essential to my question).

Setting up the Kubernetes cluster on the RasPi nodes seems to work until I try to initialize the cluster using `kubeadm init --node-name k8s-master`. Somehow the RAM of my RasPi is not recognized. The machine has 8GB of RAM, but I always get below error message.

```
[ERROR Mem]: the system RAM (1 MB) is less than the minimum 1700 MB", "\t[ERROR SystemVerification]: missing required cgroups: memory"
```

The OS of each RasPi is "Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" and the kernel is "    Linux k8s-master 5.4.83-v7l+ #1379 SMP Mon Dec 14 13:11:54 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux" (with k8s-master being the node name).

Anyone got an idea how I can fix the issue with RAM detection? Does ubuntu as OS for the RasPi nodes work better?

Comment: I have seen this error on my Raspi's using older Firmware. Update your firmware to the latest version.